# Camera Preview like Instagram

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview

I am trying to create a Camera Preview same as Instagram app, but my Camera preview shows same frame as Instagram but when i take the picture it gives me full screen image.

Below is my code :

XML :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.spurtree.townsee.utils.camera.MyFrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Myframelayout:

```
class MyFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    private static final float RATIO = 4f / 3f;

    public MyFrameLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public MyFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = getMeasuredHeight();
        int widthWithoutPadding = width - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        int heigthWithoutPadding = height - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();

        int maxWidth = (int) (heigthWithoutPadding * RATIO);
        int maxHeight = (int) (widthWithoutPadding / RATIO);

        if (widthWithoutPadding > maxWidth) {
            width = maxWidth + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        } else {
            height = maxHeight + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
```

Camera Preview Class :

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

    private Context mContext;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    public List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
        mCamera = camera;

        mSupportedPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        for (Camera.Size str : mSupportedPreviewSizes)
            Log.e(TAG, str.width + "/" + str.height);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. surfaceChanged will take care of stuff
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged => w=" + w + ", h=" + h);
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.getParameters().setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final int width = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);

        if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
            mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes);
        }

        float ratio;
        if (mPreviewSize.height >= mPreviewSize.width)
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.height / (float) mPreviewSize.width;
        else
            ratio = (float) mPreviewSize.width / (float) mPreviewSize.height;

        // One of these methods should be used, second method squishes preview slightly
        setMeasuredDimension(width, (int) (width * ratio));
//        setMeasuredDimension((int) (width * ratio), height);
    }

    public Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes)
    {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.05;
        if( sizes == null )
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        Point display_size = new Point();
        Activity activity = (Activity)this.getContext();
        {
            Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            display.getSize(display_size);

//            Log.d(TAG, "display_size: " + display_size.x + " x " + display_size.y);
        }
        double targetRatio = calculateTargetRatioForPreview(display_size);
        int targetHeight = Math.min(display_size.y, display_size.x);
        if( targetHeight <= 0 ) {
            targetHeight = display_size.y;
        }
        // Try to find the size which matches the aspect ratio, and is closest match to display height
        for(Camera.Size size : sizes)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "    supported preview size: " + size.width + ", " + size.height);
            double ratio = (double)size.width / size.height;
            if( Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE )
                continue;
            if( Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff ) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
//        if( optimalSize == null )
//        {
//            // can't find match for aspect ratio, so find closest one
//            Log.d(TAG, "no preview size matches the aspect ratio");
//            optimalSize = getClosestSize(sizes, targetRatio);
//        }
//
//        Log.d(TAG, "chose optimalSize: " + optimalSize.width + " x " + optimalSize.height);
//        Log.d(TAG, "optimalSize ratio: " + ((double) optimalSize.width / optimalSize.height));
        return optimalSize;
    }


    private double calculateTargetRatioForPreview(Point display_size)
    {
        double targetRatio = 0.0f;
        targetRatio = ((double)mCamera.getParameters().getPictureSize().width) / (double)mCamera.getParameters().getPictureSize().height;
        //targetRatio = ((double)display_size.x) / (double)display_size.y;
        return targetRatio;
    }

    public void refreshCamera(Camera camera) {
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        mCamera = camera;
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked into many posts which did not help me.